# Remote Container - Ubuntu:Latest - /dev/null: Permission denied

Tags: docker, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote

Up until recently, I had no issues with my using Remote Containers with an Ubuntu image (via a Dockerfile and docker-compose since I also need to run a mongodb container). Admittedly, I have not ran my remote container for over a month. I attempted to run my remote container on the latest version of VS Code on my Apple Silicone M1 MacBook Pro and get the below output with basically `/dev/null: Permission denied` killing the VS Code Server install. (Though the containers are actually running) I thought this was going to be isolated to running on the M1, however it occurs on my Intel MacBook Pro as well now.

Here is the output from `remoteContainers.log`:

```
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.190Z] [PID 19883] [2 ms] Remote-Containers 0.166.1 in VS Code 1.55.2 (3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d).
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.317Z] [PID 19883] [129 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.317Z] [PID 19883] [129 ms] Setting up container for folder or workspace: /Users/<redacted>/Projects/<redacted>
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.318Z] [PID 19883] [130 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.318Z] [PID 19883] [130 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.492Z] [PID 19883] [303 ms] Server API version: 1.41
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.500Z] [PID 19883] [312 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose version --short
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.779Z] [PID 19883] [591 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=<redacted>_devcontainer --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=app
[2021-04-15T00:12:46.952Z] [PID 19883] [764 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose -f /Users/<redacted>/Projects/<redacted>/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml config --services
[2021-04-15T00:12:47.256Z] [PID 19883] [1068 ms] db
app
[2021-04-15T00:12:47.256Z] [PID 19883] [1068 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:47.256Z] [PID 19883] [1068 ms] Start: Run: docker events --format {{json .}} --filter event=start
[2021-04-15T00:12:47.257Z] [PID 19883] [1069 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose --project-name <redacted>_devcontainer -f /Users/<redacted>/Projects/<redacted>/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml up -d --build
[2021-04-15T00:12:47.598Z] [PID 19883] Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

[2021-04-15T00:12:47.660Z] [PID 19883] Building app
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.162Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.162Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.163Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 0.0s (0/1)                                                                    
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.278Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 0.1s (2/3)                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.279Z] [PID 19883]  => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.427Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 0.3s (2/3)                                                                    
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.428Z] [PID 19883]  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       0.1s
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.582Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.582Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 0.4s (2/3)                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       0.3s
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.684Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.684Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 0.5s (2/4)                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       0.4s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                         0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.835Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.835Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 0.7s (3/4)                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       0.6s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                         0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.990Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 0.8s (3/4)                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:48.990Z] [PID 19883]  => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       0.7s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                         0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.141Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.141Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 1.0s (3/4)                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       0.9s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                         0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.293Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.294Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 1.1s (3/4)                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       1.0s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                         0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.365Z] [PID 19883] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.365Z] [PID 19883] [+] Building 1.2s (17/17) FINISHED                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.92kB                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                       1.1s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                         0.0s
 => [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:3c9c713e0979e9bd6061ed52ac1e9  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recomme  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/12] RUN localedef -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8     && locale-gen   0.0s
 => CACHED 
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.365Z] [PID 19883] [ 4/12] RUN groupadd --gid 1000 coder     && useradd --uid 1000 --gid 100  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/12] WORKDIR /home/coder                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/12] RUN wget https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/raw/master/tools/inst  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/12] RUN wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x -O - | sudo -E bas  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/12] RUN npm -g update                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/12] RUN npm install -g eslint                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [10/12] RUN wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-  0.0s
 => CACHED [11/12] RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] ht  0.0s
 => CACHED [12/12] RUN apt-get autoremove -y     && apt-get clean -y     && rm -rf /  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                0.0s
 => => exporting layers  
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.366Z] [PID 19883]                                                              0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:98ed4f19cd7ec4ff88e27b697c3a7bf9154cdd06436955c28ccf190f  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/<redacted>_devcontainer_app                     0.0s
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.376Z] [PID 19883] Successfully built 98ed4f19cd7ec4ff88e27b697c3a7bf9154cdd06436955c28ccf190f1376a252
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.399Z] [PID 19883] db is up-to-date
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.406Z] [PID 19883] Creating app ... 
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.792Z] [PID 19883] 
Creating app ... done
[2021-04-15T00:12:49.836Z] [PID 19883] [3648 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=<redacted>_devcontainer --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=app
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.008Z] [PID 19883] [3820 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container f745c3fa01a1
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.168Z] [PID 19883] [3980 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.168Z] [PID 19883] [3980 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container f745c3fa01a153c03fb114148d2b2a29ff560f8e92ae5b4c4dc952cf1e6512f2
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.333Z] [PID 19883] [4145 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.334Z] [PID 19883] [4146 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.565Z] [PID 19883] [4376 ms] aarch64
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.565Z] [PID 19883] [4377 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.565Z] [PID 19883] [4377 ms] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.566Z] [PID 19883] [4378 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.566Z] [PID 19883] [4378 ms] /bin/sh: 2: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.566Z] [PID 19883] [4378 ms] Exit code 2
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.566Z] [PID 19883] [4378 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.570Z] [PID 19883] [4382 ms] Start: Updating configuration state
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.574Z] [PID 19883] [4386 ms] Start: Setup shutdown monitor
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.575Z] [PID 19883] [4387 ms] Forking shutdown monitor: /Users/<redacted>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.166.1/dist/shutdown/shutdownMonitorProcess /var/folders/3w/b44z5p2j5t3glm0jtv89j8fm0000gn/T/vscode-remote-containers-57a7544ee35d334a24c2adfa9898ab4c339e8081.sock dockerCompose Info /Users/<redacted>/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/20210414T192126/exthost1/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers 1618445566188
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.576Z] [PID 19883] [4388 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /home/coder/.vscode-server
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.577Z] [PID 19883] [4389 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.577Z] [PID 19883] [4389 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.577Z] [PID 19883] [4389 ms] Exit code 1
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.577Z] [PID 19883] [4389 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /home/coder/.vscode-remote
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.579Z] [PID 19883] [4391 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.579Z] [PID 19883] [4391 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.579Z] [PID 19883] [4391 ms] Exit code 1
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.580Z] [PID 19883] [4392 ms] Start: Run in container: set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/home/coder/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/coder/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.587Z] [PID 19883] [4399 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.587Z] [PID 19883] [4399 ms] /bin/sh: 6: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.587Z] [PID 19883] [4399 ms] Exit code 2
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.587Z] [PID 19883] [4399 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /home/coder/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.592Z] [PID 19883] [4404 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.592Z] [PID 19883] [4404 ms] cat: /home/coder/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json: No such file or directory
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.592Z] [PID 19883] [4404 ms] Exit code 1
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.592Z] [PID 19883] [4404 ms] 
Support for ARM64 is in preview.

[2021-04-15T00:12:50.592Z] [PID 19883] [4404 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /home/coder/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.594Z] [PID 19883] [4406 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.594Z] [PID 19883] [4406 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.594Z] [PID 19883] [4406 ms] Exit code 1
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.594Z] [PID 19883] [4406 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit 3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.594Z] [PID 19883] [4406 ms] Start: Installing VS Code Server
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.594Z] [PID 19883] [4406 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /home/coder/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d_1618445570594
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.596Z] [PID 19883] [4408 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.596Z] [PID 19883] [4408 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.605Z] [PID 19883] [4417 ms] Start: Run in container: (dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=3764 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=15 count=1 2>/dev/null) | tar --no-same-owner -xz --strip-components 1 -C /home/coder/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d_1618445570594
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.620Z] [PID 19883] [4432 ms] 
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.620Z] [PID 19883] [4432 ms] /bin/sh: 10: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/bin/sh: 10: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.620Z] [PID 19883] [4432 ms] Exit code 2
[2021-04-15T00:12:50.620Z] [PID 19883] [4432 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[2021-04-15T00:12:53.003Z] [PID 19883] [6815 ms] Start: Installing VS Code Server
[2021-04-15T00:12:53.003Z] [PID 19883] [6815 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /home/coder/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d_1618445573003
[2021-04-15T00:12:53.003Z] [PID 19883] [6815 ms] Stdin closed!
[2021-04-15T00:12:53.006Z] [PID 19883] [6818 ms] Shell server terminated (code: 2, signal: null)
```

Here is my `devcontainer.json`

```json
{
  "name": "<redacted>",
  "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
  "service": "app",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
  // Settings speicifc to vscode instance inside of DevContainer
  "settings": {
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh" // Specifying ZSH as shell
  },
  // Extension IDs of VS Code Extensions to install
  "extensions": [
    "editorconfig.editorconfig",
    "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "mechatroner.rainbow-csv",
    "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
    "eamodio.gitlens"
  ],
  // Ports to forward to Host machine from Container network. Specifically opening:
  // a. MongoDB Admin - 27017
  // b. ngrok - 4040
  "forwardPorts": [27017, 4040],
  // Exiting DevContainer runs docker-compose down to properly shutdown containers. Default action.
  "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
  // Specifies a command that should be run after the container has been created.
  "postCreateCommand": "npm install",
  // Non-root user for Dev Container
  "remoteUser": "coder"
}
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached
    network_mode: service:db
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mongo:latest
    tty: true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /Users/<redacted>/Projects/Docker/mongoData:/data/db
```

And, finally, here `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
LABEL Maintainer = "<redacted>"

# Switching to non-interactive for cotainer build
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Specify arguments for creation of non-root user in container (created after apt installs)
# Microsoft Article on non-root users in containers: 
#   https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root-user
# For VS Code Remote Cotaniners use the "remoteUser" property in devcontainer.json
#   to use non-root user
ARG USERNAME=coder
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Configure apt and install packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \ 
    #
    # Verify git and needed tools are installed
    && apt-get -y install \ 
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        git \
        gnupg \
        iproute2 \
        iputils-ping \
        locales \
        procps \
        software-properties-common \
        sudo \
        unzip \
        wget \
        zsh 

# Configure en_US.UTF-8 Locale
## apt-get package: locales
ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
RUN localedef -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
    && dpkg-reconfigure locales

# Set up User and grant sudo privileges 
# apt-get package: sudo
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID --shell /bin/zsh --create-home $USERNAME \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME
WORKDIR /home/$USERNAME

# Install & Configure OhMyZSH
# apt-get package: zsh
RUN wget https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh || true \
    && cp -R /root/.oh-my-zsh /home/$USERNAME \
    && cp /root/.zsh* /home/$USERNAME \
    && sed -i "s/\/root/\/home\/${USERNAME}/g" /home/"${USERNAME}"/.zshrc \
    && sed -i "s/ZSH_THEME=\"robbyrussell\"/ZSH_THEME=\"maran\"/g" /home/"${USERNAME}"/.zshrc

# Install NodeJS 12 LTS via nodesource
# https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md
# apt-get package: wget
RUN wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x -O - | sudo -E bash - \
    && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Update NPM
RUN npm -g update

# Install eslint globally
RUN npm install -g eslint

# Install ngrok
# apt-get package: wget, unzip
RUN wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-arm64.tgz --progress=bar \
    && tar -xvf ngrok-stable-linux-arm64.tgz \
    && mv ngrok /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm -f ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

# Install Google Cloud SDK
# apt-get package: apt-transport-https, ca-certificates, python, gnupg & wget
# Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source:
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list \
    #
    # Import the Google Cloud public key
    && wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg -O - | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - \
    #
    # Update the list of products
    && apt-get update \
    # Install PowerShell, .NET and ASP.NET Core
    && apt-get install -y \
    google-cloud-sdk

# Clean up
RUN apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Use non-root user as default account when launching container
USER $USERNAME

# Switching back to interactive after container build
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog
```

If I console into the container I get the following errors in my console:

```
$ docker exec -it f745c3fa01a153c03fb114148d2b2a29ff560f8e92ae5b4c4dc952cf1e6512f2 /bin/zsh

compaudit:103: permission denied: /dev/null
/home/coder/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:63: permission denied: /dev/null
/home/coder/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:67: permission denied: /dev/null
handle_completion_insecurities:13: permission denied: /dev/null
/home/coder/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:88: permission denied: /dev/null
grep-flags-available:1: permission denied: /dev/null
grep-flags-available:1: permission denied: /dev/null
/home/coder/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:35: permission denied: /dev/null
/home/coder/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:35: permission denied: /dev/null
/home/coder/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:43: permission denied: /dev/null
/home/coder/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh:3: permission denied: /dev/null
git_prompt_info:3: permission denied: /dev/null                                                                                             
coder@8c9354fbe7f3:/home/coder $
```

I am doing something wrong, I must be. I've failed at Googling this for the last 4 days and hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh. As soon as I submitted this, I noticed an update to Docker. I check out the release notes for [Docker for Mac Release Notes - Docker Desktop 3.3.1](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-331):

> Bug fixes and minor changes
> Docker Desktop now ensures the permissions of /dev/null and other devices are correctly set to 0666 (rw-rw-rw-) inside --privileged containers. Fixes [docker/for-mac#5527](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5527)

As soon as I upgraded, container builds.